# pgAdmin doesn't show user's tables from Yugabyte DB

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, yugabytedb

i have installed YugabyteDB and created local cluster using this command

```
./bin/yugabyted start
```

the database is up and running , then i create the keyspaces and tables by running the following command

```
cqlsh -f resources/IoTData.cql
```

IoTData.cql contains the following :

```
// Create keyspace
```

CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS TrafficKeySpace;

```
// Create keyspace
    CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS TrafficKeySpace;

    // Create tables
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TrafficKeySpace.Origin_Table (vehicleId text, routeId text, vehicleType text, longitude text, latitude text, timeStamp timestamp, speed double, fuelLevel double, PRIMARY KEY ((vehicleId), timeStamp)) WITH default_time_to_live = 3600;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TrafficKeySpace.Total_Traffic (routeId text, vehicleType text, totalCount bigint, timeStamp timestamp, recordDate text, PRIMARY KEY (routeId, recordDate, vehicleType));
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TrafficKeySpace.Window_Traffic (routeId text, vehicleType text, totalCount bigint, timeStamp timestamp, recordDate text, PRIMARY KEY (routeId, recordDate, vehicleType));
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TrafficKeySpace.Poi_Traffic(vehicleid text, vehicletype text, distance bigint, timeStamp timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (vehicleid));

    // Select from the tables
    SELECT count(*) FROM TrafficKeySpace.Origin_Table;
    SELECT count(*) FROM TrafficKeySpace.Total_Traffic;
    SELECT count(*) FROM TrafficKeySpace.Window_Traffic;
    SELECT count(*) FROM TrafficKeySpace.Poi_Traffic;

    // Truncate the tables
    TRUNCATE TABLE TrafficKeySpace.Origin_Table;
    TRUNCATE TABLE TrafficKeySpace.Total_Traffic;
    TRUNCATE TABLE TrafficKeySpace.Window_Traffic;
    TRUNCATE TABLE TrafficKeySpace.Poi_Traffic;
```

The YB-Master Admin UI shows me that tables are created , but when i am using pgAdmin client to brows data from that database it doesn't shows me those tables.
in order to connect to yugabyteDB i used those properties :

database : yugabyte
user     : yugabyte
password : yugabyte
host     : localhost
port     : 5433

why the client doesn't show tables i have created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the client doesn't show tables i have created

The reason is that the 2 different layers can't interact with each other. YSQL data/tables cannot be read from YCQL clients and vice-versa.

This is also [explained in the faq](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/faq/compatibility/#can-i-insert-data-using-ycql-but-read-using-ysql-or-vice-versa):

> The YugabyteDB APIs are currently isolated and independent from one
> another. Data inserted or managed by one API cannot be queried by the
> other API. Additionally, Yugabyte does not provide a way to access the
> data across the APIs.

Comment: thank you for your answer , you are right , i used cassandra workbench and its working like a charm.